# Conversion of EPSG:3857 coordinate to UTM

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to convert coordinates from Google Maps using PostGIS.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-29.16297 -51.1795034)', 900913), 29182));
```

The problem is that when I put a point on the map using the UTM coordinates, it is in a different place.

Is there a chance of one of these SRIDs be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your input coordinates look as lat/long or long/lat coordinates, so you should use 4326 instead of 900913:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-29.16297 -51.1795034)', 4326), 29182));
```

Or:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-51.1795034 -29.16297)', 4326), 29182));
```

The input on that case should be POINT(long lat).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ST_MakePoint`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) and the geography type. Google Maps exports in 4326, which is the default SRID for Geography

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom)
FROM ST_Transform( ST_MakePoint(long, lat)::geography, 29182 )
  AS t(geom);
```